# How To validate with mvc on html?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to use this html

```
<input type="date" name="birthDate" id="birthDate" class="textBox1" required />
```

and make it act like

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.birthDate, new { @class = "textBox1" })
```

because i want server validation

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "must")] 
[Display(Name = "birth Date")]
public string birthDate { get; set; }
```

i want the mvc  validation work on

```
  <input type="date" name="birthDate" id="birthDate" class="textBox1" required />
```

Comment: You get server validation in both cases, provided you have coded it on the server. `TextBoxFor` can add *client-side* validation attributes.

Comment: mvc does not have date control i want to use html date control     i not using this line                              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.birthDate, new { @class = "textBox1" })

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you want to write the the html manually or do you want to use the helper and have it add `type="date"`?

Comment: MVC does not have text control either. The browser does. If you want to override value of the `type` attribute, just do so in the same place where you provide the `class` attribute.

Comment: You can just add `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.birthDate, new { @class = "textBox1", @type="date" })`